# 000webhost service website database error

Tags: php, mysql, database, logging, phpmyadmin

On my 000webhost website I had created this SQL file, named `test.sql`

Here is it's coding:

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
`id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`username` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`password` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
-- 
-- Dumping data for table `members`
--
INSERT INTO `members` VALUES (1, 'john', '1234');
```

And after that I created another php file named `main_login.php`

Here is coding:

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

After that I prepared another php file named `checklogin.php`

Here is coding:

```
$host="I INSERTED MY LOCAL HOST HERE"; // Host name 
$username="I INSERTED MY USERNAME HERE"; // Mysql username 
$password="I TYPED MY PASSWORD HERE"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="[B]I AM CONFUSED THAT WHICH DATABASE SHOULD I NAME HERE[/B]  :eek: "; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

In checklogin.php, 4th line, I am confused that which database name should I provide. I tried to write `test.sql` as I had created a table with SQL file, but while logging in it's showing error and login form is not able to fetch the SQL table data.I had already created a mySQL file in service provided by 000webhost.com and get MySQL username, MySQL database and host site (let username be `SQL_user` and site), but currently don't know how to use MySQL. **So which file should I name in `$db_name` above**? And also want to know that **how can I add data in MySQL in 000webhost.com so that login form can fetch the login info**?

Thank You in advance...

Comment: Actually I had asked the same question on 000webhost forum but I didn't get the actual answer, So I had copied and edited the question, but if there is still any BBCode there then please can you edit it.

Comment: You said you have the name of the MySQL database provided by 000webhost.com - did you try that?

Comment: Yep, But I didn't know that how to create a table in MySQL so that login form can fetch the username and password from the MySQL database. Can you tell me how I can modify my MySQL database so that login form can get the login data from that.

Comment: Go to your account manager, select the correct subdomain and click on phpMyAdmin. With this tool you can alter your db

Comment: @Lorenz You know one thing... You are really awesome. Thanks for your help. Now I got it. Actually in phpMyAdmin there was a small misunderstanding which was creating error. Well, now I got it, Thanks.

Comment: Is this sorted? If so, could someone (either @Lorenz or the OP) add an answer, so it can be accepted? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above I had asked 2 Questions:

**Que 1.** So which file should I name in `$db_name` above?

**Que 2.** How can I add data in MySQL in 000webhost.com so that login form can fetch the login info?

Here are answers:

**Ans 1.** Here in the **checklogin.php** I had to write this:

```
$host="INSERTED LOCAL HOST HERE"; // Host name 
$username="INSERTED USERNAME HERE"; // Mysql username 
$password="TYPED PASSWORD HERE"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="HERE WE HAVE TO INSERT MYSQL DATABASE NAME"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name
```

Now in above at `$db_name` we will be your **MySQL database name**, and I will have to create another table at that database.

**Ans 2.** After opening my site Control Panel at 000webhost I will have to **go on phpMyAdmin** and **create a database** first and after putting the username, password, local host etc., I will **click on "Enter phpMyAdmin"** at the right side of the table it will take us to another window and there we have to create the database and this database will be the place from where the login form will fetch data.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your account manager, select the correct subdomain and click on phpMyAdmin. With this tool you can alter your Db.

With the MySQL manager you can set the name of your database, the username and the password:

```
MySQL database name: a2748273_my_dbname
MySQL user name: a2748273_my_username
Password for MySQL user: my_password
```

These credentials are what you have to specify in your PHP script when connecting to the Db.

Comment: Ok, got it. But need more in-depth accuracy. But still nice effort